# How do parasitic fungi sense optimal fruiting conditions from inside the host?

Tags: mycology, parasitology

Question is pretty straight forward. Are there generally any chemical cues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In model fungi, the G protein coupled receptor Gpr1 is known to sense sugars and upregulate a cAMP linked PKA pathway, while in pathogenic strains, it senses Methionine. This probably is the environmental cue that sets off fruiting. There is a recently published extensive review too: [Heterotrimeric G protein signaling in filamentous fungi](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev.micro.61.080706.093432)

---

### Reference

- **Li, Liande, Sara J. Wright, Svetlana Krystofova, Gyungsoon Park, and Katherine A. Borkovich.** *“Heterotrimeric G Protein Signaling in Filamentous Fungi.”* Annual Review of Microbiology 61, no. 1 (October 2007): 423–452.